# Why in English it is considered rude to say "he is lying"

Tags: word-usage

I am foreigner and I want to describe somebody's behavior.
Why in English it is considered rude to say "he is lying". Or he is liar.

Comment: I'm really wondering in what language/culture it wouldn't be considered rude.

Comment: Is your question about how to say "he's lying" politely, or are you wondering why someone gets offended if you call them a liar?

Comment: It might be rude to say "You are a liar" but is it  rude to say "He is a liar"? (if he is a third party unrelated to the person on the other end of the conversation)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think in most languages (or at least the ones I'm farmiliar with), it would be considered rude to call someone a liar.

If you want to be more neutral, you could negate *telling the truth*, *being honest* etc. instead:

> He is not telling the truth.

However, that may still be quite direct and if you really want to avoid being rude, you could use modals to do so or other constructions:

> - He **may** not be telling the truth.
> - He **might** not be honest with us.
> - **It is likely** that he is not telling the truth.